# Zabbix web.page.regexp set output if pattern not found

Tags: web, monitoring, zabbix

I created a new Zabbix agent item to try to monitor the content of a web page, but I can't manage to make it work.

To test this, I'm using the page http://httpbin.org/get that will return a json page with whatever get parameter you put in the url.
In Zabbix I've set the following key:

```
web.page.regexp[httpbin.org,/get?a=thisisatest,80,"thisisatest",,1]
```

This works so far and returns 1, if "thisisatest" is found. In the item settings I selected the value type "Numeric (unsigned)" and "Boolean" so it can be shown as a graph.
But the problem happens, if either the regex doesn't match or the page is unavailable. Example:

```
web.page.regexp[httpbin.org,/get?a=thisisNOTatest,80,"thisisatest",,1]
```

This just returns an empty string (or nothing), so Zabbix can't parse it and the Item won't work (Error: Not supported)

Anyone knows if there's a way to get this working right, or if i'm doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

As per https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.4/manual/config/items/itemtypes/zabbix_agent , this item:

> Returns an empty string if no match was found or on fail.

You could put it in a character or text item, but that wouldn't give you a graph.

I also cannot think of a way to return different numeric values using regexps.

Comment: I found out that the zabbix host doesn't even support https, so we'll probably  try something else more flexible. Thanks for the help anyways